# How to access elements of 1-D array through some other 1-D array?

Tags: arrays, julia, flat

I am very new to Julia, even new to programming. Therefore, please excuse me for simple doubts.

consider the below Matlab Example:

```
A=[10; 20; 30; 40; 50];
B=[1; 3; 5];
```

The result of `A(B)=0` in the matlab shall be `[0.0 20 0.0 40 0.0]`.

How do I achieve the same in Julia for 1-D array??

I have a variable `A` and `B`:

```
julia> A
5×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 10
 20
 30
 40
 50

julia> B
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 3
 5
```

when I execute this `A[[B]]`

`ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid index: Array{Int64,1}[[1, 2]]`

HOWEVER, this statement provides this result:

```
julia> A[[1, 3 ,5]]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 5
 3
 1
```

Please guide me. I know that Julia has the flat array, but how to access them through any other flat array.

Comment: Hi Nit_GUP, it is not really clear to me what you actually want do do. Regarding your error, it is just the difference between `A[[1, 3, 5]]` (works fine) and `A[[[1, 3, 5]]]` (errors because a vector of vectors is not a proper vector of indices).

Comment: Hello Crstnbr, Thank you for writing to me. I wish to get the result of Matlab's statement: A(B)=0, in Julia. If I execute this statement: A[B]=0, in Julia, the result is 0; whereas in matlab the result is [0.0 20 0.0 40 0.0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra pair of brackets.

```
A[B]
A[ [1; 3; 5] ]
A[ [1, 3, 5] ]
A[ [1 3 5] ]
A[ 1:2:5 ]
```

all work as desired. You can index an array with any valid index or any collection of indices.

However, `A[[B]]` tries to index `A` at the location `[1;3;5]`, which is an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result by overwriting the elements of `A` at indices given by `B` with zeros as follows:

```
julia> A=[10; 20; 30; 40; 50];

julia> B=[1; 3; 5];

julia> A[B] .= 0;

julia> A
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
  0
 20
  0
 40
  0
```

Here, the dot assignment `.=` indicates to change the elements of A in-place.

Comment: Okay. That is a very basic thing I didn't know. If I can ask you, is there any good reading source where I can start learning these nuances? I appreciate your help in this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In general, the Julia documentation is fairly easy to read. Have a look [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Array-and-Vectorized-Operators-and-Functions-1) and [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators-1) for example. I also recommend [this blog post](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots)